# Parsing an array with emty element

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

Hello I am trying to parse a file into an array which contains empty elements

Sample file (`test`)

```
test11|test12|test13|test14
test21||test23|test24
```

the following funtion just print the array elements

```
test_func()
{
    local param=($@)
    echo "1: ${param[1]}, 2: ${param[2]}, 3: ${param[3]}, 4: ${param[4]}"
}
```

And now I call this function as follows

```
while IFS=\| read f1 f2 f3 f4
do
    arr=("$f1" "$f2" "$f3" "$f4")
    test_func ${arr[@]}
done < test
```

I am using `zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)`. I got the following output

```
1: test11, 2: test12, 3: test13, 4: test14
1: test21, 2: test23, 3: test24, 4:
```

Note that in the second line the elements are shifted to the left.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Can someone please help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add double quotes like `"$@"` and `"${arr[@]}"` ?

Comment: Try: `test_func() {local param=("$@"); echo "1: ${param[0]}, 2: ${param[1]}, 3: ${param[2]}, 4: ${param[3]}"; }` (double quote `$@` and first index is 0).

Comment: I have ealier used double quotes, as suggested by @Philippe. As for the second comment, the output I get is `1: , 2: test11, 3: test12, 4: test13`

Comment: @SudiptaRoy, for the 2nd row you'll need to output the 2nd empty field `||` as `2:  ,`. Are you able to apply gawk ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest can you please elaborate. That is exactly what I want.

Comment: @SudiptaRoy, Are you able to apply/use gawk ?

Comment: Also double quote `${arr[@]}`. If you don't double quote `$@` or `${arr[@]}` empty positional parameters or array cells are skipped. While with double quotes they expand as separate empty words.

Comment: @Philippe: Should make no difference.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : This is also something I suspected, but trying it with `arr=(a b c '')` and `test_func "$arr[@]"` also did not work. To make sure that I don't confuse an empty element with an undefined element, I run the code with `set -u`, and even with double quotes, I get a _test_func:3: param[4]: parameter not set_, which demonstrates that the parameter is indeed missing.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : With some experimentation (printing `$4` at the start of the function), I found that indeed the assignment of  `($@)` is dropping the element, so you are right that both `${arr[@]}` and `$@` must go between quotes. I have seen that you already had this in an answer, but deleted it. Your only error in your answer was the indexing part, because zsh arrays are indexed starting from 1. May I suggest that you re-introduce the correct part of your answer?

Comment: Unquoted parameter expansions are not subject to *word-splitting*, but `${arr[@]}` does not produce separate words due to word-splitting. If you leave the expansion unquoted, it produces unquote *words*, not unquoted parameter expansions, and an unquoted empty string simply "goes away".

Comment: @RenaudPacalet If you undelete your answer (and fix the indices), I will delete mine.

Comment: @chepner My answer was a `bash`-only one that I wrote before the OP clarified that they wanted to use `zsh`. As I am not a `zsh` expert I prefer to let you answer.

Comment: OK, just checking :) Nothing about your answer was `bash`-specific, and applied to `zsh` as well. (Just the array indices needed to be updated, but even the point about 0-indexing is true if the `KSH_ARRAYS` option is set. `zsh` is nothing if not flexible...)

Comment: @RenaudPacalet you suggestion was indeed correct. If you post the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote both `${arr[@]}` and `$@` in order to preserve the empty sting produced by each.

Unquoted parameter expansions are not subject to *word-splitting*, but the separate elements produced by an array expansion are not due to word-splitting. They are individual words in their own right, so failing to quote either the expansions mentioned above produces unquoted *words*. An unquoted empty string simply "goes away". If you leave `$arr[@]` unquoted, the empty string never makes it into `test_func`, and if leave `$@` unquoted, the empty string is not present in the assignment to `param`.

```
test_func()
{
    local param=("$@")
    echo "1: ${param[1]}, 2: ${param[2]}, 3: ${param[3]}, 4: ${param[4]}"
}

while IFS=\| read f1 f2 f3 f4
do
    arr=("$f1" "$f2" "$f3" "$f4")
    test_func "${arr[@]}"
done < test
```

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier with `awk` command:

```
awk -F'\\|' -v OFS=', ' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=i": "$i }1' test.txt
```

---

```
1: test11, 2: test12, 3: test13, 4: test14
1: test21, 2: , 3: test23, 4: test24
```